# Creating tables and triggers dinamically

Tags: postgresql

Can I automatize the creation of tables and triggers to this table ?

I need to create one table every month and this table needs a trigger...

Is It possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The Relational Model of Data advocates storing data in columns of rows in tables. That is, it suggests that storing data--such as year and month--in a table's name might be a Bad Thing. In my experience, it's a Very Bad Thing.

Instead, store the year and month in a column of a row in the table. Use suitable CHECK constraints. (Don't allow storing month 13 or year 32, for example.) Or store a date, from which year and month can easily be derived; columns of type "date" won't allow invalid months, although you might still want to use a CHECK constraint to limit the range of valid dates. *Valid dates* are application-dependent.

If you're concerned about the number of rows--you *probably* shouldn't be--read up on indexing, indexing expressions, and partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike is quite right about avoiding creating such tables, but sometimes there is some external (say, Business one) need to have such possibility.

So yes, this is possible in postgres.

You could have, let's say, some procedure which could internally call things like `EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE myDynamicTable' || year || '_' || month || (...)'` with following similar `EXECUTE` commands for triggers.

You could also use some external language like Python, which would just concatenate dynamically - in more readabale fashion most likely - similar strings with `CREATE TABLE...`, `CREATE TRIGGER...`, etc.

You should also make sure that regardless of chosen solution, it will be scheduled to be called once a month, etc., but it strongly depends on your technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

From [CREATE_TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html) documentation:

> PARTITION OF parent_table { FOR VALUES partition_bound_spec | DEFAULT }

> Creates the table as a partition of the specified parent table. The table can be created either as a partition for specific values using FOR VALUES or as a default partition using DEFAULT. **Any indexes, constraints and user-defined row-level triggers that exist in the parent table are cloned on the new partition.**

And the example from the same docs:

```
Create a range partitioned table:

CREATE TABLE measurement (
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);

...

Create partition of a range partitioned table:

CREATE TABLE measurement_y2016m07
    PARTITION OF measurement (
    unitsales DEFAULT 0
) FOR VALUES FROM ('2016-07-01') TO ('2016-08-01');
```

So postgresql already does much of the work for you.